# LXC bridge with several IP addresses

Tags: networking, bridge, lxc, containers

While trying to setup a small server with LXC containers, I encountered a problem:

I want to assign 4 different IP addresses: 1 address for the host and 3 addresses in a different net for the containers.

Setting up 4 IP addresses using virtual interfaces (eth0:1, eth0:2, etc)  is no problem at all - but LXC doesn't work with those virtual interfaces.

The host's IP address is 2.2.2.2 (net mask 255.255.252.0). The 3 container IP addresses are 33.33.33.33, 33.33.33.44 und 33.33.33.55. Net mask for all of them: 255.255.255.255.

I'm struggling while setting up the network for hosts and containers. Other posts explain similar settings, with different, but controllable subnets ([bridging LXC containers to host network with different IP range](https://serverfault.com/questions/641728/bridging-lxc-containers-to-host-network-with-different-ip-range)) or suggest using virtual interfaces ([Several IP address within the same subnet on the same host](https://serverfault.com/questions/197752/several-ip-address-within-the-same-subnet-on-the-same-host)) which we cannot do here.

This is my configuration:

### Host: interfaces file

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*  

auto lo                            
iface lo inet loopback              

auto br0                        
iface br0 inet static          
    address 2.2.2.2  
    netmask 255.255.252.0  
    broadcast 2.2.2.255
    gateway 2.2.2.1    
    bridge_ports eth0      
    bridge_fd 0            
    bridge_maxwait 0        

auto br0:1                    
iface br0:1 inet static        
    address 33.33.33.33
    netmask 255.255.255.255
auto br0:2                    
iface br0:2 inet static        
    address 33.33.33.44
    netmask 255.255.255.255

auto br0:3                    
iface br0:3 inet static        
    address 33.33.33.55
    netmask 255.255.255.255
```

This is the only way I know to bind several IP addresses to an interface. The bridge needs to listen to the container's IP addresses to retrieve packets, doesn't it?

### Container: interfaces file

Small file, since all parameters are kept in the LXC configuration.

```
auto lo                
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0              
iface eth0 inet manual
```

### LXC: network configuration

This is the network part of my LXC configuration file:

```
lxc.network.type = veth                  
lxc.network.flags = up                  
lxc.network.link = br0                  
lxc.network.name = eth0                  
lxc.network.ipv4 = 33.33.33.33/32    
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 2.2.2.2
```

However, the connection just doesn't work. An address is assigned to the container, but IP packets sent from the container do not reach the host.

Here is the output of `ip` and `route`:

```
root@container:~# route -n                                                      
Kernel IP routing table                                                      
Destination     Gateway   Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         2.2.2.2   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
2.2.2.2         0.0.0.0   255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0



root@container:~# ip 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UPmtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
15: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UPmtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP
group default qlen 1000    
    link/ether ae:af:7c:e4:b5:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    inet 33.33.33.33/32 brd 255.255.255.255 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
    inet6 fe80::acaf:7cff:fee4:b54d/64 scope 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And the same details given by the host:

```
root@host:~# route -n                                                        
Routing Table 
Destination     Router      Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface  
2.2.2.0         0.0.0.0     255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 br0    
0.0.0.0         2.2.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0    

root@host:~# ip 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UPmtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft        
    inet6 ::1/128 scope 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UPmtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0
state UP group default qlen 1000  
    link/ether 2e:cf:22:12:dd:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
16: veth93SMLW: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UPmtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state
UP group default qlen 1000      
    link/ether dd:c1:1e:68:90:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    inet6 fe80::fcc1:1eff:fe68:9047/64 scope 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
17: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UPmtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group
default                          
    link/ether 4d:cf:22:12:dd:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:
    inet 2.2.2.2/22 brd 1.1.1.255 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
    inet 33.33.33.33/32 brd 2.2.2.2 scope global br0:
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
    inet 33.33.33.44/32 brd 3.3.3.3 scope global br0:
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
    inet 33.33.33.55/32 brd 4.4.4.4 scope global br0:
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft 
    inet6 fe80::829:caff:fece:bbd7/64 scope                             
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Have you got hints which part of the configuration I messed up?

Thanks for your help!